# How do I use useRef inside useContext with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hooks

I would like to use `useRef` inside my Next.js global `useContext` function. I am struggling to know how to properly use `useRef` there and access it globally bearing in mind that I am using `typescript`. So, here is what I tried and the error that I am seeing:

```
interface tripAttributes{
   tripTitle: string

  }

const initialTripState: tripAttributes = {
    tripTitle: ''
  }

 

export const BookingContext = createContext<{tripsData: tripsAttributes, setTripData: 
React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<tripsAttributes>>}>
({tripsData: initialTripState, setTripData:() => initialTripState})


export const BookingProvider = ({children}: reactNodeAttributes)=>{
   const [tripsData, setTripData] = useState<tripsAttributes>(initialTripState);
    const userAuth = useRef<RefObject<null | string>>(null)

    return(
       <BookingContext.Provider value={{tripsData, setTripData, userAuth}}>
         {children}
       <BookingContext.Provider/>
     )
 }
```

With the current codes, I can access the trip and setTrip functions globally. I would like to achieve same with useRef. Currently, it is not working. Typescript says it is not part of the properties I passed to `BookingContext` which is understandable because it is not part of the properties yet. So, how can I achieve this? How can I make useRef work with useContext and become availalable globally so that I can update the useRef state globally like this:`userAuth.current = value`?

Comment: You didn't declare it here: `createContext<{tripsData: tripsAttributes, setTripData: 
React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<tripsAttributes>>}>`

Comment: Yea, that is because I don't know how it is declared there. That is what I am looking for

Comment: `createContext<{userAuth: RefObject<null | string>, tripsData: tripsAttributes, setTripData:  React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<tripsAttributes>>}>`?

Comment: How about the createContext parameter value for the userAuth? I tried adding it and giving it a value of null but it didnt work: createContext<{userAuth: RefObject<null | string>, tripsData: tripsAttributes, setTripData:  React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<tripsAttributes>>}>({userAuth: null})

Answer (score 0):

Explanation in the comments

```
interface tripAttributes {
  tripTitle: string;
}

const initialTripState: tripAttributes = {
  tripTitle: "",
};

// I moved type declaration so it's easier
interface BookingContextData {
  // declare userAuth here
  userAuth: RefObject<null | string>;
  tripsData: tripsAttributes;
  setTripData: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<tripsAttributes>>;
}

// create context with undefined as a default value
export const BookingContext = createContext<BookingContextData | undefined>(undefined);

export const BookingProvider = ({ children }: reactNodeAttributes) => {
  const [tripsData, setTripData] = useState<tripsAttributes>(initialTripState);
  const userAuth = useRef<null | string>(null);

  return (
    <BookingContext.Provider value={{ tripsData, setTripData, userAuth }}>
      {children}
    </BookingContext.Provider>
  );
};

// create a helper hook that will throw an error if it's used without the provider
export const useBookingContext = () => {
  const context = useContext(BookingContext);

  // this will ensure that context is defined in the components
  if (!context)
    throw Error("useBookingContext must be used within BookingProvider");

  return context;
};
```

Comment: where is the helper hook going to be called?

Comment: Every time you would call `useContext(BookingContext)`

Comment: well, this is a large app and this context was called in many places. Is there a way to use UseEffect for this once?